# CURL not working on live server but working on local server?

Tags: php, mysql, json, curl, file-get-contents

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
<thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Client Name</th>
      <th>Location</th>
      <th>Distance Travelled</th>
      <th>Travel Track</th>                                       
    </tr>
</thead>
<?php 
    include 'db.php';
    $sql = 'SELECT travel_allwnce.date_of_travel, location.latitude, location.longitude, meeting_details.client_cname FROM travel_allwnce INNER JOIN meeting_details ON meeting_details.uid = travel_allwnce.uid INNER JOIN location ON location.uid = travel_allwnce.uid';         
    $travel = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);     
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($travel)) 
{?>         
<tbody>
    <tr class="active">
    <?php
        $latlong = $row[1].','.$row[2];
        $url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng={$latlong}&sensor=false";
        $ch = curl_init($url);          
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $output = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        $geocode = json_decode($output);
    ?>
    <td><?php echo $row[0];?></td>                  
    <td><?php print_r($geocode->results[0]->formatted_address);?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row[3];?></td>            
    <td><?php echo $row[3]?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row[3]?></td>             
    </tr>                               
</tbody>
```

> Same code works fine on localhost. but gives error on local server.
>   Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in
>   /home/adnacbsllp/adtrack.adnacgroup.com/tables.php
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in
>   /home/adnacbsllp/adtrack.adnacgroup.com/tables.php
>
> please help me with the same.

Comment: check your apache server if curl is enabled.

Comment: i am using curl for push notifications too from another page and its working there. only this page is having this issue.

Comment: I suggest you to use debugger like XDebug to see what's happen step by step

Comment: try to print the `$output`. Is it blank? or print your `$row`

Comment: What about this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42778184/how-to-convert-lat-long-to-address-in-php-with-json-api/42778789#comment72673476_42778789

Comment: @Niklesh that's working on local only. same code gives same errors on live server

Comment: i remove one on load event that was unnessary.  @AlexSlipknot and its working now thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Are the error messages actually missing the line numbers?